# Failed to evaluate expression 'filesCompleter' error in file_picker library

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I wanted to browse files from web browser and using "https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker" library. However, code crashes and I am getting above mentioned error. I do not know why, I think it should not crash but I also think that may be it is crashing because of null safety. I am using Flutter 3.3.10 stable version. Any solution to avoid it?

Here is my code.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';

class BrowseFiles extends StatefulWidget {
  const BrowseFiles({super.key});

  @override
  State<BrowseFiles> createState() => _BrowseFilesState();
}

class _BrowseFilesState extends State<BrowseFiles> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("File Browser"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () async {
            //FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(allowMultiple: true);
            FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
              type: FileType.custom,
              allowedExtensions: ['pdf', 'doc'],
            );
            if (result != null) {
              //  File file = File(result.files.single.path!);
              List<File> files = result.paths.map((path) => File(path!)).toList(); //crashes here
              print(files[0]);
            } else {
              // User canceled the picker
            }
          },
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            width: 500,
            height: 100,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0), color: Colors.amber),
            child: const Text("Browse Files"),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```